# Uniquely identify Thingworx things

Tags: iot, uniqueidentifier, thingworx

I've set up an application key, shape, service, and thing, and am ready to update the thing using REST calls.  However, I will have potentially thousands of things of the exact same type, though each with a unique serial number.  What I'm unclear on is how I manage this in Thingworx.  Does the thing identifier account for this, and if so, how?  Also, when updating values, how do I specify which 'thing' the updates apply to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,Thing identifier does not account for uniquely identify things .This is for remote binding devices with thing so that you can access remote properties into a thing .For identifying things ,the name of thing is the only property that is unique and you need to update by name only .I hope i understood your question in right direction .

Answer (score 0):

On the part of the question about updating the property, the name of the thing will be the way to specify the thing to update in addition to the name of the property being updated.